# Logging python tenacity retry_state with logger from outer scope

Tags: python, logging, python-logging, python-tenacity, tenacity

I have a module that includes a utility function with a tenacity retry tag

```
from tenacity import retry, stop_after_attempt, wait_random

def log_attempt_number(logger, retry_state):
  logger.info(f"Attempt number {retry_state}")
  logger.info("Logger is not recognized here unless we instantiate in this file")

@retry(stop=stop_after_attempt(3), wait=wait_random(min=1, max=3), before=log_attempt_number)
def retry_function(logger, driver):
  logger.info("Outer scope logger works fine here")
  source = driver.page_source
  return source
```

Since the `retry_function` is used in other scripts, I want to be able to use those scripts' existing loggers for output, rather than instantiate a logger within this module. However, I cannot figure out how to pull in the outer scope logger for use in the `log_attempt_number` function, since it is only called within Tenacity `@retry` which doesn't seem to actually take in the arguments.